# Construct a set of anticommutative operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, operator-theory

Suppose that I have a set of infinitely many operators $\mathbb{A} = \{ A_1, \dots , A_n \}$ with $n \mapsto \infty$. All operators satisfy

$A_i A_j + A_j A_i = 0$ for all $i,j \in \{ 1, \dots, n \}$.

Moreover I assume that $\mathbb{A}$ is a set of linear operators such that these operators can be represented as an (infinite-dimensional) matrix.

Question: Is there a general form of such matrices satisfying above relations? How can I construct these matrices?

Comment: The problem as you state it is not "well-posed". By a general form you probably mean a classification. For that you need additional restrictions. E.g. $A_i$ are self-adjoint bounded operators on a Hilbert space. Otherwise you cannot even classify a couple of such operators.

Comment: I forgot to mention other conditions: These Operators are defined on a Hilbert space and they satisfy $A_i^\dagger=A_i$ for all $i$, i.e. all Operators are hermitean Operators.

Comment: Are they bounded?

Comment: What about an infinite product of [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Commutation_relations)? They anticommute...

Comment: yes, These Operators are bounded.